# Residue Conway's problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Exercise 9, cap. V, section 2. 
Let $λ > 1$ and show that the equation $λ−z−e^{−z }= 0$ has exactly one solution in the half plane $\{z : Re z > 0\}$. Show that this solution must be real. What happens to the solution as $λ → 1$?

How solve this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $f(z)=z-\lambda$ and $g(z)=e^{-z}$. Choose half circle $C$ on the right half plane centered at $0$ with arbitrary radius $r>\lambda$ (The line of half circle is on $y$ axis from $(0,-r)$ to $(0,r)$). Show that $|f|>|g|$ on $C$. Then use Rouché's theorem to show that $f$ and $f+g$ have same number of zeros inside $C$.

To prove the solution is real, let $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$. Then the imaginary part of $λ−z−e^{−z }= 0$ become
$$
r\sin\theta=e^{-r\cos\theta}\sin(r\sin\theta), \quad r>1, -\pi/2\leqslant \theta \leqslant \pi/2
$$
Since $-1<-r\cos\theta\leqslant 0$, $e^{-r\cos\theta}\leqslant 1$. Also there is 
$$
\sin\theta<\theta,\:0<\theta \leqslant \pi/2
$$
Thus 
$$
r\sin\theta=e^{-r\cos\theta}\sin(r\sin\theta)<r\sin\theta
$$
This contradiction means $\theta=0$, i.e. the root must be real.

Comment: Thanks! What was missing was this semicircle of radius greater than lambda. Thank you